# Building a sql query from two tables

Tags: sql

I created a query which selects sum of columns from a table grouped by a field in Crystal reports, now I want the result to be filtered by a date range from another table which I am unable to do. Please Help...

Here is the query

```
SELECT 
    BDETAIL.HSN, 
    SUM(BDETAIL.TAXABLE), 
    SUM(BDETAIL.SGST_V), 
    SUM(BDETAIL.CGST_V), 
    SUM(BDETAIL.TOTAL), 
    BDETAIL.SGST_P 
FROM 
    BDETAIL 
JOIN 
    BILL ON BDETAIL.BILL_ID = BILL.BILL_ID 
WHERE 
    BILL.BDATE BETWEEN {?FROM_DATE} AND {?TO_DATE} )
GROUP BY 
    BDETAIL.HSN, BDETAIL.SGST_P
```

Comment: Your query looks fine to me. What's the issue with it? Are you getting a syntax error message? There is a closing paranthesis too many here: `{?TO_DATE} )`.

Comment: Removed it but still getting error.....Syntax Error in From Clause

Comment: Post the exact query you are running and the exact error.

Comment: the complete query is given above, the error I am getting is : Not Supported

Comment: DAO error code: 0xc3b

Comment: Does it return data if you remove the WHERE clause? Does it return data if you hardcode a date range in the WHERE clause?

Comment: Have you tried something like WHERE BILL.BDATE BETWEEN '{?FROM_DATE}' AND '{?TO_DATE}'

Comment: The error still exists when I remove the WHERE clause, what does it indicate?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out ..here is the working query

```
SELECT BDETAIL.HSN, 
sum(BDETAIL.TAXABLE), 
Sum(BDETAIL.SGST_V),
Sum(BDETAIL.CGST_V),
Sum(BDETAIL.TOTAL),
BDETAIL.SGST_P
FROM BDETAIL INNER JOIN BILL ON 
( BILL.BILL_ID = BDETAIL.BILL_ID AND 
BILL.BDATE BETWEEN {?FROM_DATE} AND  {?TO_DATE} )
GROUP BY BDETAIL.HSN, BDETAIL.SGST_P;
```

thank you all for showing interest in my issue.